# Maximum and minimum over a curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

How do I determine the maximum and minimum values (and points) of a given function along a curve?

Ex: $f(x,y)=xy$; $5x^2+5y^2+6xy - 64=0$

Using Lagrange multipliers, I got to this system of equations, but I don't see any easy way to solve it:

$$y = \lambda (10x+6y)$$
$$x = \lambda (10y+6x)$$
$$5x^2 + 5y^2 + 6xy = 64$$

Thank you!

Comment: Lagrange multipliers is the tool

Comment: That's what I tried, but I get to a really complicated system of equations :/...

Comment: It is simple. Please, post your work in order one can see where and/or why you are stuck and be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track!

With the equations you have, you just have to solve for lambda.

So:

\begin{equation} \lambda = \frac{y}{10x+6y}
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation} \lambda = \frac{x}{10y+6x}  
\end{equation}

Equate them to each other, and simplify. You'll see that the relationship between them is 
\begin{equation}
\label{eq}
x^{2} = y^{2}
\end{equation}
Solve for either x or y, your choice, and plug that into the constraint equation so that you can solve for one variable. 
Then, relate back to ($x^{2}=y^{2}$) to find the other variable. You will get some points, which you just plug into your $f$ to find the maximum/minimum values.